# I don't know why " var Level = class Level {....//etc..} "

Tags: javascript, class, object, variables, new-operator

I have a question about this class in JavaScript.
I am a newbie of JavaScript, as normally, we are using `new` for new object of class, but I see in here that they using `var`.

For example, from Eloquent Javascript:

```
var Level = class Level {
  constructor(plan) {
    let rows = plan.trim().split("\n").map(l => [...l]);
    this.height = rows.length;
    this.width = rows[0].length;
    this.startActors = [];
    this.rows = rows.map((row, y) => {
      return row.map((ch, x) => {
        let type = levelChars[ch];
        if (typeof type == "string") return type;
        this.startActors.push(
          type.create(new Vec(x, y), ch));
        return "empty";
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: `var Level = class Level` this isn't needed and is likely a typo. --- I'm pretty sure that without `new` the constructor will not run.

Comment: Using `var` here goes together with a `class` expression instead of a `class` statement. It doesn't influence the fact that you need to use `new` to create an instance of that class.

Comment: Eloquent is online isn't it? Can you point to the page where this code it?

Comment: @Andy the `var Level = ` must be a mistake. It's not in the current book https://eloquentjavascript.net/16_game.html#c_ObYKMNTKci, it's not a class in the second edition https://eloquentjavascript.net/2nd_edition/15_game.html#c_PTlscRwogG ,and isn't even in the first edition...

Comment: Thank you for your coment, here is a link for this https://eloquentjavascript.net/code/chapter/16_game.js

Comment: I tried to find any information for this. I appreciate if you can help me to understand. Thank you very much

Comment: @Andy could you help a check, thank you

Comment: @haiStudent it's a typo. `var ClassName = ` is not needed before `class ClassName`.